# Whats pinging my Azure App every 13 seconds (admin/host/ping)

Tags: .net, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

We are currently in the process of migrating to Azure, we have setup 3 environments (dev,stage,prod), this problem only occurs in prod and prod is the only environment to use autoscaling so I am assuming its related to that.

I have setup an App Service Plan and deployed several apps (dotnet) with autoscaling and the 'Always On' configuration is turned off. I have also setup App Insights and connected all the apps to this.

For some reason, each app is being pinged http://appname.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/ping every 13 seconds which obviously results in a response 404 and polluting the logs.

Does anyone know why this could be? and how I can stop this?

I have tried stopping, restarting the apps and I have tried turning off/on 'Always On' but doesn't make a difference. Can't seem to find any alerts which could be doing this either.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me. It started on July 19th. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @clenard nope, no idea yet. You?

Answer (score 4):

The requests are coming from the load balancer when the app service plan is using autoscaling. Disable autoscaling and this should go away.

Comment: In my case the pings definitely started when autoscaling was enabled, but turning it off did NOT stop this.  Investigating with Microsoft support.

Comment: Any luck anyone? every app is still getting pings every 13 seconds, literally have thousands of 404 errors

Comment: Hey, any luck with the problem? I tried disabling the automatic autoscale feature but it didn't stop the pings from coming. I wonder what's causing them.

Comment: Anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason, each app is being pinged http://appname.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/ping every 13 seconds which obviously results in a response 404 and polluting the logs.

It is caused by Azure Application Insights' "Availability" monitoring feature. Azure Application Insights periodically sends HTTP requests to an endpoint of your application to check its availability and responsiveness.

- If you don't want these availability pings to be sent to your app, you can disable the "Availability" monitoring feature in Azure Application Insights.
- Open your application insights in your function app and navigate to **Investigate** section then click on **Availability** please check below.

[image]

- Enter the URL of your app endpoint that you want to ping for availability and set the test's "Enabled" option to "Disable".
- Modify the availability test to use a different endpoint that does not exist or responds with an HTTP 200 status code.

Comment: Thank for your reply, I have tried this, still no luck...

Comment: Use network monitoring tools to track the incoming requests to your Azure App Service. use the latest version of the Application Insights SDK in your .NET application. Older versions might have different behavior regarding availability tests.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the automatic auto-scale feature, which is still in preview mode. I turned it off and switched to rule-based auto-scale instead. That solved the issue and the ping went away. I hope they will fix the automatic auto-scale feature soon, because it was a nice option to have.